# What is the idiomatic way of iterating over a lazy sequence in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, io, lazy-evaluation

I have the following functions to process large files with constant memory usage.

```
(defn lazy-helper
    "Processes a java.io.Reader lazily"
    [reader]
    (lazy-seq
          (if-let [line (.readLine reader)]
                  (cons line (lazy-helper reader))
                  (do (.close reader) nil))))
(defn lazy-lines
    "Return a lazy sequence with the lines of the file"
    [^String file]
    (lazy-helper (io/reader file)))
```

This works very well when the processing part is filtering or other mapping or reducing operation that works with lazy sequences quite well.

The problem starts when I have process the file and for example send every line over a channel to worker processes.

```
(thread
  (doseq [line lines]
    (blocking-producer work-chan line)))
```

The obvious downside of this is to process the file eagerly causing a heap overflow.

I was wondering what is the best way of iterating over each line in a file and do some IO with the lines.

[image: Growing heap]

It seems this might be unrelated how the file IO is handled, doseq should not hold onto the head of the reader.

As @joost-diepenmaat pointed out this might not be related to the file IO and he is right.

[image: clojure.data.json$write_str.doInvoke]

It seems the way I am working with JSON serialization and deserialization is the root cause here.

Comment: "The obvious downside of this is to process the file eagerly causing a heap overflow." why would that be the case? Also: `line-seq` is a builtin.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat not sure I might be wrong. I am enabling Java Mission Control and checking what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [(line-seq rdr)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) which "returns the lines of text from rdr as a lazy sequence of strings".

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with the JSON handling of the code and not the file IO. Explanation in the original post.